# Cambiar src de imagen dinámicamente en Angular con Material Option

Tags: angular, typescript, materialize

Quiero cambiar la imagen dinámicamente en mi etiqueta `<img [src]="" />` con el `object` que traigo desde una `API` https://reqres.in/api/users usando el selector de opciones de material:

```
<!-- Esta es la imagen que quiero cambiar por medio del mat-option -->
<img [src]="object[idSelecionado].avatar" alt="Foto de la persona" />

<mat-form-field appearance="fill"  >
        <mat-label>Persona</mat-label>
        <mat-select >
          <mat-option  *ngFor="let persona of object" [value]="persona.id">
            {{ persona.first_name }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Este es el servicio con el que traigo el objeto desde la API:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PhotosService {

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  getPhotos(id):Observable<any>{
    return this._http.get('https://reqres.in/api/users');
  }
}
```

Y este es mi componente en donde quiero poner que cada vez que seleccione un nombre del `<mat-option>` me cambie la imagen sin necesidad de recarga la pagina o presionar un botón:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],

})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'angular-material';
  object: any;
  id;
  idSelecionado;

  constructor(public photos: PhotosService) {
    this.idSelecionado = 0;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.photos.getPhotos(this.id).subscribe(
      result => {
        this.object = result.data;
        console.log(this.object);
        console.log(this.object.first_name) 
      }
    )
  }

}
```

Obtengo los nombres de las personas dentro de mi `<mat-option>` pero no se como transportar esa selección para que cambie la imagen que le corresponde a cada persona dinámicamente.

Comment: ¿Qué contiene la variable `object[idSeleccionado].avatar`?

Comment: Es el objeto que traigo desde la API, específicamente el avatar de la persona con el id 0, ya que idSelecionado lo inicialice en el constructor con un valor de 0 para que siempre se muestre el primer elemento del objeto hasta que yo seleccione otra opción con el mat-option.
En el link del API deje la estructura del objeto que recibo, las personas están dentro de la propiedad 'data'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola Junner por lo que veo estas usando angular material y estas usando mat-option, entonces aprovechemos el poder que nos brinda angular material... si nos vamos a la API, de este componente mat select podemos observar que tiene un método output que dice lo siguiente.

> ```
> @Output()
> selectionChange: EventEmitter<C>
>
> Event emitted when the selected value has been changed by the user.
> Evento emitido cuando el usuario ha cambiado el valor seleccionado.
> ```

Entonces en tu archivo

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill"  >
        <mat-label>Persona</mat-label>
        <mat-select (selectionChange)="cambiarFoto($event)">
          <mat-option  *ngFor="let persona of object" [value]="persona.id">
            {{ persona.first_name }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

En tu ts agregas la función de cambiarFoto y recibes en este caso la opción seleccionada y te recomiendo hacer un pipe de sanatizer cuando trabajes con imagenes que vienen de archivos externos te dejo este link https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/angular-safe-pipe-implementation-to-bypass-domsanitizer-stripping-out-content-c1bf0f1cc36b.